# View is not rendering correctly in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have moved a view from folder to Shared folder. When I try to navigate from controller to the shared view it is navigating to the default view and not the shared view. I checked in Global.asax, I created new route in the Global.asax, but it is still pointing to the default route and loading the default view.

Could anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Need more details. What is default view, why it should go to shared view and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the old view is deleted, otherwise it will always pick that one over the shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

if you have not explicitly defined the name of the view e.g lets suppose you have an ActionResult in `Home` controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

the view by the name of `Index.aspx` and/or `Index.ascx` is searched first in the `Home` folder which is present in the Views folder if a matching veiw is found there it is not searched further. If it is not found then it will be searched in the `Shared` folder

make sure you have deleted the view form the Default location